# Is anyone able to reproduce Hinton's matrix capsule networks?

Tags: deep-learning, capsule-neural-network

I've been working on Hinton's matrix capsule networks for several months. I searched each corner of the internet. But I couldn't find anyone that can reproduce Hinton's [matrix capsule network](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=HJWLfGWRb). Can anyone get the reported accuracy on SmallNORB and Cifar10 dataset?

PS: I know Hinton's another paper on capsule networks [Dynamic Routing Between Capsules](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/6975-dynamic-routing-between-capsules.pdf) is reproducible. Please, do not confuse the two papers.

Comment: Have you considered emailing the authors? If you spent months working on this and searching online I doubt anyone here would have better results.

Comment: I just did what you suggested. Hope to get a reply.